# How do I cast my NSArray to List<String> in xamarin ios

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nsarray

In my xamarin ios project I am fetching some array from a file

Using

```
NSArray TimeFilePath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("Time","txt");
            arrTime =  NSArray.FromFile(TimeFilePath);
```

Now I have to convert TimeFilePath to a List

I tried the following but It failed

```
List<string>items = (List<string>)TimeFilePath;
```

Help me out how do I convert NSArray to List in C#

Comment: Doesn't NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource return a string? How are you assigning it to a NSArray.

Comment: @Andres Castro  .FromFile method Takes a string Parameter which is file path and arrTime has a valid array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the list from `arrTime` (not `TimeFilePath`) as `PathForResource` returns a `string` so your **cast** in your question is not using the correct variables.

There's many ways to do it but I suggest you use the .NET, not Apple, API to achieve this, e.g.

```
var TimeFilePath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("Time","txt");
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines (TimeFilePath);
var arrTime = List<string> (lines);
```

Comment: Since my file is a PList Array file ,,above code is crashing by saying cannot read file

Comment: Your original said `PathForResource("Time","txt");` I just changed that because I did not have a file by that name (fixed).

Comment: Yea , I have used my file name itself, But it crashed

Comment: Is your `Time.txt` a plist ? If so then I do not see how turning it into a `List<string>` would help (plist are either XML or binary).

Answer (score 1):

I needed it to be done in one line and it took me quite some time to figure out, so I'm sharing my result here.

It is possible to do with Linq by using Enumerable.Range.

This example does it by iterating the NSArray and calling ToString() on every object in the NSArray and calling ToList() at the end.

```
Enumerable.Range(0, (int)((NSArray)arrTime).Count)
   .Select(i => ((NSArray)arrTime)
   .GetItem<NSString>(nuint.Parse(i.ToString())).ToString())
   .ToList()
```